# How to combine different field types in flask-wtf wtforms

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am building a form using flask-wtf forms. I have a field where users can select multiple options. If the choice they want isn't in my list, I would like to allow users to select "other" and specify their option via a textfield.

I have found no way to do this in wtforms. I have googled around and cannot seem to find an answer anywhere. My scenario here is not at all unique, and I believe it would be quite common. So I think I could be thinking/going about it wrong.

```
question1_options = [('rice','rice'),('chips','chips'),('tuna','tuna'), ('other', 'other')]
question2_options = [('yes', 'yes'),('no', 'no')]

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    q1 = SelectMultipleField('favourite food?', choices=question1_options)
    q2 = RadioField('do you like football', choices=question2_options)
```

**What I want to achieve:**

Combine `SelectMultipleField` with a `StringField` so that if the appropriate options are not in the list, users can select "other" and input what they would like.

Comment: my first idea: flask may not have this functionality and it will need JavaScript for this.

Comment: thats a shame. i guess i'll need to look into how to do that. do you have any possible links you can share on how thats done

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to add `StringField` for `other` and add `RadioField` to select `SelectMultipleField` or `StringField`. To test it I would need minimal working code but I don't know if I want to build it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find method to combine two fields.

I think it should be two separated fields visible all time

```
q1_options = [('rice','rice'),('chips','chips'),('tuna','tuna')] #, ('other', 'other')]

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    q1 = SelectMultipleField('Favourite food?', choices=q1_options)
    q1_other = StringField('Other favourite food?')
```

or it should use `JavaScript` to show `StringField` when you select `other`.

I tried to create minimal working code.

Because it uses `multiple select` so it needs more complex `JavaScript` code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectMultipleField, StringField, RadioField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Optional

# --- form ---

q1_options = [('rice','rice'),('chips','chips'),('tuna','tuna'), ('other', 'other')]

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    q1_list  = SelectMultipleField('Favourite food?', choices=q1_options, validators=[DataRequired()])
    q1_other = StringField('Other', validators=[Optional()])

# --- app ---

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'qwerty123456'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    #print(dir(form))
    print(form.validate_on_submit())
    #if form.validate_on_submit():
    if form.is_submitted():
        print('list:', form.q1_list.data)
        print('other:', form.q1_other.data)

    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>    

<form method="POST">
    {{ form.q1_list.label }}<br>
        {{ form.q1_list(onchange="get_selection(this);") }}<br>
        {{ form.q1_other(style="display:none") }}<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<script language="javascript">
//var q1_list  = document.querySelector("#q1_list");
var q1_other = document.querySelector("#q1_other");

function get_selection(select){
  //console.log(select);
  //console.log(select.value);
  //console.log(select.options);

  var opts = [];
  var opt;    
  
  var len = select.options.length;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    opt = select.options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      opts.push(opt.value);
    }
  }    
  
  //console.log(opts);
  
  if(opts.includes('other')){
    q1_other.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    q1_other.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
''', form=form)

# --- start ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

---

The same with `addEventListener` instead of `onchange`

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.q1_list.label }}<br>
        {{ form.q1_list() }}<br>
        {{ form.q1_other(style="display:none") }}<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<script language="javascript">
//var q1_list  = document.querySelector("#q1_list");
var q1_other = document.querySelector("#q1_other");

q1_list.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  //console.log(event);
  //console.log(event.target.value);
  //console.log(event.target.options);

  var select = event.target;
  
  //console.log(select.options);

  var opts=[];
  var opt;    
  
  var len = select.options.length;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    opt = select.options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      opts.push(opt.value);
    }
  }    
  
  //console.log(opts);
  
  if(opts.includes('other')){
    q1_other.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    q1_other.style.display = 'none';
  }
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot furas Legend! i will play around with this and intergrate it into my code. thanks for clarifying how to achieve this through the use of combining with js